# javascript external called function does not return value

Tags: javascript, function, return

I cannot figure out why I cannot get the data from an external function in dataFunctions.js

If I call this function directly in my main function it works.

Return the value doesn't work

Here is my main function :

```
import { searchAndRemove, findItem, insertItem } from '../helpers/dataFunctions'

  const dragDrop = function () {
    const { isDraggingId, zonePosition, isDraggingOverId } = state

    const newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.value))

    const itemToMove = findItem(newArray, isDraggingId)
    console.log("1", itemToMove) // <==== I get undefined

    searchAndRemove(newArray, isDraggingId)

    insertItem(newArray, isDraggingOverId, zonePosition, itemToMove)

    saveNewArray(newArray)
  }
```

here is dataFunctions.js

```
export const findItem = (array, id) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    const result = array[i]
    if (result.id === id) {
      console.log('2', result) // <====  Here i get the expeted object that I want to return
      return result
    } else {
      if (result.children) {
        findItem(result.children, id)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I tried to copy and paste some of your code here https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-1-h4w31?file=/src/App.js and it worked. Your ```itemToMove``` will be undefined if ```isDraggingId``` doesn't match with any id in ```newArray```

Comment: that's crazy because It find the result in the console.log(2) but the result is not passed to my variable in my main function. So i think the problem is that i try to return the value from external function inside a variable, what you exemple is not showing